# How to shift Black to Color in an Image, Python

Tags: image, colors, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have a new backlit led monitor, and I found this black and white image of a storm trooper that looks fantastic on the backlit monitor.  My other monitor, however, is an old "energy star" liquid crystal, and the whites are yellow and the blacks are brown.  The same background looks awful...

So, I was trying to write some code to create a negative of the image, then shift the base grays and blacks to a color.  However, I guess I don't understand enough about color theory.  I tried the following on the negative of the image:

```
def colorshift_image(hueshift,image_file,output_image_file):
    image = imread(image_file)
    hsv_image = colors.rgb_to_hsv(image)
    hsv_image[:,:,2] += hueshift
    image = colors.hsv_to_rgb(hsv_image)
    imsave(output_image_file,image)
```

and it doesn't do much of anything, except maybe make the image look worse:

Original:

[image]
Negative:

[image]

Hue Shift:

[image]

Actually, it looks moderately awesome in the lower resolution.   But **anyway**, I think the gist is that I would like the extreme whites to take on a color--in fact, keeping this last image as a base (because the color palette is good for the LCD, then adding a blur to soften the jarring hue transitions, I think it would work...if only I could move from the grays and whites: shift them to some kind of color...

Is there a way to grab, using PIL/Scipy/etc., the "shiny" bright white parts, and shift it to a red or blue...and the greys to another base color?

Comment: Yes, all of that is possible. First, for the color,  take a look at histograms, then I'd try something specific and come back with a  more detailed question. For the blur look at convolution.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Thanks man.  I will update the question as I learn more about this..